# How to synchronize windows server date/time?

Tags: windows, time, time-synchronization

I administer multiple Windows servers. One issue I have is that the time gets out of sync, and this becomes noticeable over a week or so.

For example, my app server system time could be different from my database server time.

What can I do to automatically synchronize the timing across multiple servers?

Answer (score 4):

If the machines are members of an Active Directory domain the time synchronization should happen automatically and you would be best served to investigate why the normal domain time synchronization mechanisms are failing.

If they're not domain members I'd recommend configuring each machine with an NTP time source (such that they're not dependent on each other for time sync). If you've got an on-site NTP server then use it but, if not, something like an "ntp.org" source is probably reasonable.  You could get away with something like:

```
w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org,0x8 1.pool.ntp.org,0x8 2.pool.ntp.org,0x8 3.pool.ntp.org,0x8" /syncfromflags:MANUAL
```

Answer (score 4):

If they are members of an Active Directory domain, they will automatically sync from the domain controllers. If you manage multiple Windows servers, you should run AD.

If they are standalone servers, you can set the Sync From Internet Time option in the time applet to the same NTP servers. Check out NTP.org for good time server pools.